# angular fontawesome library compound names and use regular icon

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm having problems with fontawesome library compound names ie faEyeSlash look at the IconEyeSlashComponent component below.

and I'm looking for a way to use regular icons as well.

What's the way to use it ?

Is there a way to use regular icon ?

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  faEnvelope,
  faEye,
  faEyeSlash,
  faKey
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(
  faEnvelope,
  faEye,
  faEyeSlash,
  faKey
);

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-envelope',
  template: `<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'envelope']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconEnvelopeComponent{}

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-eye',
  template: `<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'eye']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconEyeComponent{}

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-eyeslash',
  template: `<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'eye-slash']"></fa-icon>`,//THIS DOESN?T WORK
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconEyeSlashComponent{}

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-key',
  template: `<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'key']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconKeyComponent{}
```

### UPDATE

Sorry it works it's a typo :(

Comment: Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58464715/1994201](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58464715/1994201) answer for question [Argument of type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IconDefinitionOrPack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067036/argument-of-type-icondefinition-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-iconde). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I use them like so:

```js
import { faLongArrowAltLeft, IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export class MyComponent {
  faLongArrowAltLeft: IconDefinition = faLongArrowAltLeft;
}
```

```html
<fa-icon [icon]="faLongArrowAltLeft"></fa-icon>
```