# Argument of type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IconDefinitionOrPack'

Tags: angular6, font-awesome

I'm using [Angular 6 angular-starter](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter)  and fontawesome, followed [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) on how to install fa to ng.

In my .ts looks like this:

```
import { library, dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faInstagram } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faInstagram';
import { faLink } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faLink';

public ngOnInit() {
    library.add(faInstagram);
    library.add(faLink);
    dom.watch();
}
```

Then in .html:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'instagram']"></fa-icon>
```

It works perfectly fine except for free brands, `@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`. On build (npm start) it produces error/warning `Argument of type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IconDefinitionOrPack'. 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IconPack'. signature is missing in type 'IconDefinition'.` on the 92% build but actually the build appears to be successful and the instagram icon shows up but I'm bothered because a red line below the code appears.

Can someone figure it out?

My package.json

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.6",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.4.2",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.1",
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll mention a case with regular icons. Hope a similar approach will help you. You can just import the icon and then typecast it from **IconDefinitionOrPack** to **IconDefinition** while adding it to the library in your module constructor.

```
import { faTimesCircle, faCheckCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
```

Then while adding it in library typecast it

```
  export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
      library.add(faTable);
      library.add(faChartArea);
      library.add(faTachometerAlt);
      library.add(faTimesCircle as IconDefinition);
      library.add(faCheckCircle as IconDefinition);
    }
  }
```

In HTML,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'check-circle']"></fa-icon>
   <span>Tax Info</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply casting the imports to another type is really not how this should be fixed. There is some kind of version mismatch in your package.json. Please take a look at this issue: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/12575

Comment: @DanteC I think with newer font awesome npm package, `library.add()` is not required. Instead, you can assign icon directly to a variable and then pass it as input to `<fa-icon [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon>`.